# Lost table values in postback asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, but I am familar with working in WebForms.  I have a question regarding when I do a postback. Below is my model, view and controller:

**Model:**

```
public class CategoriesViewModels
{               
     [Display(Name = "ID")]
     public long ID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
     public string NAME { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Sube imagen para la categoría")]
     public string PICTURE { get; set; }
     public string PATHPICTURE { get{ return PathFiles.Avatar + PICTURE; } }
     public List<SubCategoriesViewModels> SUBCATEGORY { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
     public SubCategoriesViewModels NEW_SUBCATEGORY { get; set; }
     public bool? ResultCorrect { get; set; }
     public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
     public bool? ResultCorrect_Subcategory { get; set; }
     public string ResultMessage_Subcategory { get; set; }

     public CategoriesViewModels()
     {
         SUBCATEGORY = new List<SubCategoriesViewModels>();
         ResultCorrect = null;
         ResultCorrect_Subcategory = null;
     }
 }

 public class SubCategoriesViewModels
 {
     [Display(Name = "ID")]
     public long ID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
     public string NAME { get; set; }
 }
```

**View:**

```
@model Q2BTeamWeb.Models.CategoriesViewModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Categories", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "categories-form", id = "categories-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     if (Model.PICTURE != null)
     {
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PICTURE)
     }
     <div class="panel form-horizontal">
         <div class="panel-heading">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                     <h4>Detalle categoría</h4>
                     <a href="@Url.Action("List", "Categories")" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Volver</a>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel form-horizontal">
         <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         @if (Model.PICTURE != "" && Model.PICTURE != null)
                         {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.PATHPICTURE)" style=" width: 100%;" />
                         }
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-10">
                         <div class="col-sm-4">
                             <div class="form-group no-margin-hr">
                                 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PICTURE, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                 <input type="file" name="upFoto" id="upFoto" class="form-control" />
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NAME, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NAME, new
                            {
                                @class = "form-control",
                                placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NAME),                                      required = "Obligatorio"
                            })
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel form-horizontal">
         <div class="panel-footer">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                     @if (Model.ResultCorrect != null && Model.ResultCorrect.Value)
                     {
                         if (Model.ResultCorrect == true)
                         {
                            <label style="color:green;font-size:16px;">
                               @Model.ResultMessage
                            </label>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             <label style="color:red;font-size:16px;">
                                  @Model.ResultMessage
                              </label>
                          }
                     }
                     <input type="submit" value="@(Model.ID == 0 ? "Crear" : "Actualizar")" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="return checkForm();" name="createCategory" />
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ListSubcategories", "Categories", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "categories-form", id = "categories-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>Listado subcategorías</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @if (Model.SUBCATEGORY != null)
                        {
                            <table class="table table-striped" id="subcategories">
                              <tr>
                                  <th>
                                      Nombre
                                  </th>
                                  <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              @foreach (var subcategory in Model.SUBCATEGORY)
                              {
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subcategory.NAME)
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <span class="pull-right">
                                              <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Categories", new { id = subcategory.ID })" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
                                          </span>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                }
                          </table>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>Nueva subcategoría</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NEW_SUBCATEGORY, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NEW_SUBCATEGORY, new
                               {
                                   @class = "form-control",
                                   placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NEW_SUBCATEGORY),
                                   required = "Obligatorio",
                               })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel form-horizontal">
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @if (Model.ResultCorrect_Subcategory != null && Model.ResultCorrect_Subcategory.Value)
                        {
                            if (Model.ResultCorrect == true)
                            {
                                <label style="color:green;font-size:16px;">
                                    @Model.ResultMessage_Subcategory
                                </label>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 <label style="color:red;font-size:16px;">
                                     @Model.ResultMessage_Subcategory
                                 </label>
                             }
                        }
                        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="return checkForm();" name="createSubcategory" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public CategoriesController() { }

 public ActionResult List()
 {   
     List<CategoriesViewModels> lCategories = new List<CategoriesViewModels>();

     foreach (DataRow r in CategoriesManagement.list(null).Rows)
     {
         CategoriesViewModels c = new CategoriesViewModels();
         c.ID = long.Parse(r["ID"].ToString());
         c.NAME = r["NAME"].ToString();
         lCategories.Add(c);
     }

     return View(lCategories);
 }


 public ActionResult Detail()
 {
     string __id = (string)this.RouteData.Values["id"];
     string create_ok = Request.QueryString["create"];
     CategoriesViewModels Category = nenter code hereew CategoriesViewModels();

     if (__id != null)
     {
         foreach (DataRow r in CategoriesManagement.list(long.Parse(__id)).Rows)
         {
             Category.ID = long.Parse(r["ID"].ToString());
             Category.NAME = r["NAME"].ToString();
             Category.PICTURE = r["PICTURE"].ToString();

             foreach (DataRow r2 in SubCategoriesManagement.list(categoriesId: long.Parse(__id)).Rows)
             {
                 SubCategoriesViewModels s = new SubCategoriesViewModels();
                 s.ID = long.Parse(r2["ID"].ToString());
                 s.NAME = r2["NAME"].ToString();
                 Category.SUBCATEGORY.Add(s);
              }
         }
     }

     if (create_ok == "ok")
     {
         Category.ResultMessage = "Creado correctamente";
         Category.ResultCorrect = true;
     }

     return View(Category);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Detail(CategoriesViewModels c)
 {
     if (Request.Params["createCategory"] != null)
     {
         HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["upFoto"];
         string directory = @Server.MapPath("~/Images/Categories");
          if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
          {
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
               photo.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
               c.PICTURE = fileName;
           }

           try
           {
               long id_return = c.ID;
               c.ResultCorrect = true;
               CategoriesManagement.action(ref id_return, c.NAME, c.PICTURE);
               if (c.ID == 0)
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Categories", new { id = id_return, create = "ok" });
               }
               else
                   c.ResultMessage = "Actualizado correctamente";

               return View(c);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               c.ResultCorrect = false;
               c.ResultMessage = "Error " + ex.Message;
           }    
       }

       return View(c);
        }
```

My problem is when I postback from the first submit where I do an update in the database table from the bottom of the list, then I have to the postback lost values.

What should I do to prevent this?

In WebForms I have a gridview and this data is stored in memory and not lost like in MVC.  Do I need to return to the query to avoid losing data or would be?

Comment: OK...I think I understand what your after. Yes you must post to the controller everything that you want to keep if your using this design pattern, you can pass the values back as query parameters or put the values into a session variable and then read them from inside the controller. Better I think is to use an "ajax like" pattern so that you can refresh small portions of your page using partial views. This way you only post and return the peaces of data that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick response. I've been thinking and I will use ajax.
Thank you very much again :)